# application crashes with trace errors

Tags: android, kotlin

obtain this error java.lang.NullPointerException at com.example.myhouse.TasklistFragment.updateInterface(TasklistFragment.kt:121) at com.example.myhouse.TasklistFragment.onCreateView(TasklistFragment.kt:113)

where the code is

```
private const val ARG_TASKLIST_TYPE = "tasklist_type"
private const val TASKLIST_TYPE_TODO = 0
private const val TASKLIST_TYPE_DOING = 1
private const val TASKLIST_TYPE_DONE = 2

class TasklistFragment : Fragment(){
    private lateinit var visibleColorPaletteViewList : List<View>
    lateinit var taskRecyclerView: RecyclerView

    private var tasklistType : Int = -1
    private var adapter : TaskViewAdapter? = TaskViewAdapter(LinkedList<Task>())
    private var colorPaletteIsVisible : Boolean = false
    private var callbacks: Callbacks?=null

    //Callback interface to delegate access functions in MainActivity
    interface Callbacks{
        fun addTaskToViewModel(task: Task, destinationTasklistType: Int)
        fun deleteTaskFromViewModel(tasklistType: Int, adapterPosition: Int)
        fun getTaskListFromViewModel(tasklistType: Int) : LinkedList<Task>
    }

    //Attach context as a Callbacks reference to the callbacks variable when fragment attaches to container
    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        callbacks = context as? Callbacks?
    } 
 private fun updateInterface(){
        val tasks = callbacks!!.getTaskListFromViewModel(tasklistType)
        adapter = TaskViewAdapter(tasks)
        taskRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
    } //throws the trace error
```

Comment: Nobody can help you if you don't post the stacktrace, or the code it says is throwing the error

Comment: ive edited the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting a `NullPointerException` because you're trying to use something that isn't supposed to be null, but it is. That's happening here, in `updateInterface`:

```
val tasks = callbacks!!.getTaskListFromViewModel(tasklistType)
```

`!!` is a very bad sign, that's you telling the null-checking system that it's wrong, and `callbacks` definitely isn't null, and you don't need to check it. But it is null, that's why you're getting the NPE. (You should really avoid using `!!` because it leads to errors like this, instead of safely handling things)

You're initialising `callbacks` as null, then doing this:

```
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    callbacks = context as? Callbacks?
}
```

`onAttach` [*does* run before `onCreate`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment#onAttach(android.content.Context)) (which stacktrace says is the start of where the error is happening) but `context as? Callbacks?` is going to fail, because the `Context` you're getting from the system doesn't implement your `Callbacks` interface. The cast fails, and because you're using `as?`, instead of throwing a cast exception it evaluates to null. `callbacks = null` basically. So it's null when you call `getTaskListFromViewModel` on it, and that's where your app crashes

If you need to access functions on your activity, use `activity as Callbacks?` and be prepared to handle the potential null. You can find out exactly when the activity is created, but [it's a little more complicated now](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle)):

> To get a callback specifically when a Fragment activity's onCreate is called, register a androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleObserver on the Activity's Lifecycle in onAttach, removing it when it receives the CREATED callback.

Comment: @yanishappadoo all your methods in ``Callbacks`` are related to view models - are you sure you don't just want to access the viewmodel directly in the fragment? That's how you're supposed to use them, then you can avoid having to go through things like a parent activity, and you don't need to worry about any of this stuff. Just do ``val myModel: MyViewModel by activityViewModels()`` at the top of your fragment, then you can set up an observer on it to watch for your tasks, tell it to delete a thing etc. Your Activity doesn't need to be involved (and ideally shouldn't be)

Comment: @cactustictas you got linkedin?